# How to close a dialog when clicking on it?

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, click

I have a dialog in my activity and i want to close it by clicking on it ( in addition of clicking anywhere else, which is the normal way to do this ).

How do I manage to do this ? My dialog XML just contain an imageview !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since ImageView descends from View, you could set a `View.OnClickListener` that calls your dialog's `dismiss()` method.